# Force for electron movement $F= \frac{k}{d^2}$

Tags: calculus

An electron is fixed at $ x = 0$. Electrons repel each other with formula $F= \frac{k}{d^2}$ where k is proportionality constant. Find the work done in moving a second electron along the x axis from x = 10 to x = 1.

I don't know what this means or where to start, there are too many variables. I think this is the set up.

$$\int_{10}^1 y*F   dy$$

$$\int_{10}^1 y*\frac{k}{d^2}   dy$$

$$\int_{10}^1 y*\frac{k}{y^2}   dy$$

I am not sure about this but I know work is force times distance so my integral needs to take that into account I think.

Comment: Is the use of $y$, rather than $x$, as the variable along the $x$-axis an attempt to confuse me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work done in moving the electron between start $a=10$ and finish $b=1$ is

$$\int_a^b dx \, F_e(x)$$

where $F_e$ is the electrostatic force between the electron and the fixed electron at $x=0$.  This work done is equal to the change in electric potential energy between the points $a$ and $b$, as the force is conservative.

The electrostatic force is

$$F_e(x) = \frac{k q^2}{x^2}$$

where $q$ is the charge of an electron.  The fact that $F_e(x) \gt 0$ means that the force is repulsive.

The resulting integral is very simple to do.

Comment: I just don't follow most of what you said and I don't know what k and d are in my equation. Did I not set it up right?

Comment: $k$ is $Ce$, where $C$ is Coulomb's constant and $e$ is the electron charge. I think.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: I was hoping you'd see that your integral for the work is wrong.  You have an extra factor of $y$.

Comment: @RonGordon Can you elaborate on what I need to do? I added the y to compute for the work, because work is force * distance and y is distance.

Comment: An element of work $dW = F(y) \, dy$; where $dy$ is a small distance.  Thus, $$W = \int_a^b dy \, F(y)$$

Comment: But isn't d just what is F(y)? the function k/d^2?

Comment: @PaulthePirate: yes, but express as $F(y)=k/y^2$ to be precise.

Comment: So then d is my y variable and what is k? Do I just pull it out?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9666/discussion-between-ron-gordon-and-paul-the-pirate)

Answer (score 1):

The simplified version of the formula for work done is $W=Fd$ for a constant force $F$. But in the case of two electrons, they are in a force field created by each other. In this field, changing the position of any of the electron changes the force applied on both the electrons, so force is a function of distance $\triangle x$ from each other given by:

$F(x) =\frac m {x^2}
$ where $m=ke^2$.

(Note that we are working in $1D$ space, so distance here is a function of position, i.e., $ x= \dot x_2- \dot x_1$ where $\dot x_1$ and $\dot x_2$ are positions of the electrons on the $x$-axis)

So we use the integral form of work done, since force is dependent on $x$. This is given by:

$W=\int_{a}^{b}F(x)dx$

You might ask that we are just integrating $F(x)$ and not work done. Remember that integration is along a path or a curve. The right way to perceive it would be that we are integrating the function $F(x)$ along a path in the $x$-axis starting from $a$ and ending at $b$. So our distance aspect of the work done formula is the distance of the path travelled.

So plug in the appropriate values and solve in the integral formula. Just a hint that the work done for your problem would be positive, since the electron moves against the force, its like walking against the wind.